# Chart.js canvas and chart width gets overwritten when redrawn

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, chart.js

My charts that I made with chart.js grow each time when I redraw them and I have no idea why.
My code for the chart cavas is:

```js
let tempChart = document.getElementById("tempChart").getContext('2d');
let pressureChart = document.getElementById("pressureChart").getContext('2d');
let O3Chart = document.getElementById("O3Chart").getContext('2d');
let PM1Chart = document.getElementById("PM1Chart").getContext('2d');
```

```html
<canvas id="tempChart"></canvas>
<canvas id="pressureChart"></canvas>
<canvas id="O3Chart"></canvas>
<canvas id="PM1Chart"></canvas>
```

This is the code I call each time when I want to draw or redraw a chart:

```js
function createChart(chartLabels, chartData, chart, label, backgroundcolor, beginAtZero, borderColor) {

    let LineChart = new Chart(chart, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: chartLabels,
            datasets: [{
                label: label,
                data: chartData,
                backgroundColor: backgroundcolor,
                pointRadius: 0,
                borderColor: borderColor
        }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: false,
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: beginAtZero
                        }
                }
                ]
            }
        }
    })

}
```

The CSS of the canvas before I run createChart once:

```css
    width: 45%;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
```

CSS after I run createChart:

```css
    display: block;
    height: 341px;
    width: 683px;
```

I have tested this code with empty and full arrays for my labels and data and in both instances the chart grows each time I call the createChart function.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the library you’re using (chart.js) is overriding those css values by default.

One option is to set those values back to their correct values at the end of createChart function.

For example:

```
tempChart.style.width = 45%;
```

Other option is add a high power to them in a stylesheet, `!important`, but this depends on the way (chart.js) is acting.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like the only (quit stupid honestly) fault was that I forgot to put responsive to true. Once I did that it worked again, but thank you for your answer!